# Why is it necessary in Flow to annotate parameters of a class method that are defined in its interface?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

When using the following:

```
export interface IClass {
  test(arg: String)
}

export class MyClass implements IClass {
  test(arg) { console.log(arg) }
}
```

Why do I get the following from the flow parser:

```
test(arg) {
     ^^^ parameter `arg`. Missing annotation
```

I mean, the interface is annotating the required `test` signature, no?

Comment: I [can't reproduce this](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAdgFwKYBOUAhgMZ5gCSAwjMQM71gDeqYY+9OAFMQQOYAuMAGUcBbPwCUwgG5wMAEwDcqAL7pSdRmACyAT1oMmGALYAHGHlN5cTGtqat2nHn2kswpOFnpwrAHTw-LwCUmAaakA).

Comment: If you `export` the class it reproduces. I'll suggest an edit once the edit queue is no longer full.

Comment: Please see my edit. The real code had these as `export`s.

Comment: This is probably possible, but it likely falls into the category of "things that would be sort of nice but nobody is ever going to get around to them." Ultimately it's not that much work to add a few annotations. The team has much more pressing work to do.

Comment: This open issue seems to be a match: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3798 You may wish to add your question/feedback there.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, so we can label this as a bug.